# Why can I implicitly convert char* to const char* but not unsigned char*

Tags: c++

The following code snippet produces a compile error:

```
char a = 'a';
const char* a_ = &a;
unsigned char b = 'b';
const char* b_ = &b;
```

The last line produces the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char*'
```

I can implicitly convert from `char*` to `const char*`, but I cannot do the same for `unsigned char*`? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Try to declare `b_` as an unsigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer to a non-constant object can be implicitly converted to pointer to a constant object of the same type. So these declarations

```
char a = 'a';
const char* a_ = &a;
```

are valid.

Now let's consider the following declarations (for clarity the qualifier `const` is removed)

```
unsigned char b = 'b';
char* b_ = &b;
```

The expression in the right hand side has the type `unsigned char *` while the initialized object has the type `char *`. These two types are different and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another. Instead you can write

```
unsigned char b = 'b';
char* b_ = reinterpret_cast<char *>( &b );
```

In this case the both entities in the right hand side and in the left hand side have the same type. So you now can add the qualifier const for specification of the declared object

```
unsigned char b = 'b';
const char* b_ = reinterpret_cast<char *>( &b );
```

In C and C++ the types `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three different types. The type `char` can behave either as the type `signed char` or as the type `unsigned char` (can have the same range of values) but this does not make it signed or unsigned char.

Answer (score 7):

You can add constness to the pointee. That's permitted because it's useful and safe.

But you can't just randomly change the pointee's type beyond that.

You're saying "I have a pointer to a `char`, hey, here it is, whoops no it's a `unsigned char`" and you cannot do that without a C-style "force" cast or a `reinterpret_cast`.

This is the right code:

```
char a = 'a';
const char* a_ = &a;
unsigned char b = 'b';
const unsigned char* b_ = &b;   // (added "unsigned" here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you store a value to a `signed char x;` and then fetch it through either `signed char *xp = &x;`  (via `*xp`) or a `signed char const *xcp =&x;`, you get the same value. Always.

But if you have `signed char x = -1;` and you fetch it through an `unsigned char*` pointer, you get a different value (255, barring exotic architectures).

That's why `INT *ip` can be assigned to `INT const *` but not to `UINT *` (where `INT` and `UINT` is any signed integer type and its unsigned counterpart).

The strict aliasing rules still allow you to access `INT` values via `UINT` pointers and vice-versa, but you need an explicit cast to obtain such a pointer (pointing to a differently signed version of the original type).

---

Note: `char` has unspecified signedness. It's either like `signed char` or like `unsigned char`, but it is a type distinct from both of these (unlike every other integer type, where `signed INT` is the same as `INT` (except in bitfields)).